# rxjs "switch to" after expand ends

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have the following:

```js
const outputFile = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
const requisitionData = this.login().pipe(
  map(response => response.data.token),
  switchMap(loginToken =>
    this.getRequisitions(loginToken).pipe(
      expand(response => {
        const nextPage = response.data.content.meta.cursor.next;
        console.log('Next Page: ' + nextPage);

        return nextPage
          ? this.getRequisitions(loginToken, nextPage ?? undefined)
          : EMPTY;
      }),
      map(response => response.data),
      map(requisitions => this.processRequisitions(requisitions, outputFile)),
    ),
  ),
);

requisitionData.subscribe();
```

Basically this is what it does:

- Calls a login endpoint and returns the token string
- Pass the token string and calls a "get requisitions" endpoint
- Traverse the paginated result and calls the next page(s)
- For each page, save the result into a file

I want to modify this to call a function after all the pages have been traversed, to add a `console.log('Process finished');`.

However, no matter what I do (I tried adding `tap(() => console.log())` in various places) it always get called multiple times.

EDIT:

I managed to do this by changing the `subscribe()` and passing the callback to the 3rd parameter:

```js
requisitionData.subscribe(
  undefined,
  undefined,
  () => console.log(`Process Finished: Output file: ${outputFile.path}`),
);
```

Although I still wonder how I can achieve this within the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an Observer to tap to only do something on complete:

```ts
tap({ complete: () => console.log('Process Finished') })
```

Answer (score 0):

You completing the sequence by returning [EMPTY](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/empty.html). You need to return of(null) something else if you wanna reach map operator.

```
return nextPage ? this.getRequisitions(loginToken, nextPage ?? undefined) : of(null)
```